# changing native vlan the mngmt vlan should be seperate, right or wrong? And, which device ip default gateway to use on access Distro core

Tags: vlan, ip

Please help clear this up, I've read too many posts that just don't get it.

If change access and distro to
native vlan 5 
device Mngmt vlan 100 
blackhole 999

connections from core to distro should be L3, correct?
What about the core switches and router do they need changing to vlan 5 also and their device Mngmt to int vlan 100? for access distro and core switches, what should be ip default-gateway?

PLease help, from reading so many posts, it seems like the answer may be just too obvious to give clear answers or noone really cares about this detail.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two important things to remember:

1. VLAN tagging is specific to a particular port, not the whole switch.
   A VLAN can be tagged on port 1, but untagged (native) on port 2.
2. When two switches are connected with a trunk, the VLAN tagging
   should be the same on both trunk ports.  If VLAN 100 is tagged on
   one side of the trunk, it should also be tagged on the other.

VLANs are layer 2 constructs, so if you have layer 3 connections, VLANs have no meaning, only IP addresses.

[This question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-and-how-are-ethernet-vlans-tagged) might be helpful

Comment: But all routers and L3 switches are already set to vlan1, so I'm wondering how that native traffic passes between them if my distro and access switch are changed to native5.

Comment: And on the L3 router and core switch there is still the management of the device int vlan 100 in this case so you would want to communicate to those devices over your L3 connections, am I being clear enough?

Comment: Again, there are no VLANs on L3 ports.  you may have a VLAN on your core switch, but when you connect that switch to your distro with a L3 link, all VLAN information is removed.  The distro switch has no idea what VLAN you had on the core.

Comment: Also, you keep saying things like  "my switch is set to native vlan 5."   VLAN tagging is applied to switch ports, not switches in general.  So your statement makes no sense.

Comment: In the context of moving everything from vlan 1, so there are no ports or mngmt int vlans on vlan 1, so there has to be a native. If that makes my prediciment clearer.

Comment: As you say the core and distro have no idea about the vlans then how can we access the device management on L3 devices when that network is not added to a routing table

Comment: Unless you create a separate L2 connection, you can't.  If you want to reach an address over a L3 connection, you have to route.  If your goal is to restrict management access on your core switch, the best way is to route the management IP normally, and apply an access list to block unwanted hosts.

Comment: If your core switch has only L3 connections to other switches, then whatever VLANs you create on the core switch don't matter, as no other device can see them.

Comment: Forgot when acessing the router via ssh any port connection can be used, the int vlan1 or whatever your switching network device managment vlans are is simply not used - that clears things up considerably. Thanks

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer, so it doesn't keep popping up on the site looking for an answer.

Comment: hey Ron, I have no idea how to accept the answer, no button jumping out at me, ah found the wee tick !!